# javafx ubuntu windows look

Tags: forms, javafx

Is there anything that I need to change / setup for a JavaFX application to look the same in both Ubuntu and Windows?

Here is what I get:

[image: windows-ubuntu]

Why I get that white space in bottom & right part?

thanks

Update 2013/10/18 main.fxml

```xml
<Pane fx:id="mainPane" maxHeight="535" maxWidth="380" prefHeight="535" prefWidth="380" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="ro.data.MainController">
</Pane>
```

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("main.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 380, 535);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
```

Thant background image is in style.css

Comment: Post the code you used to generate the images.

Comment: This is from Windows 7 - 8 Window Style. If you go Clasic Theme on Windows 7, the border will disappear